# Citing an accepted manuscript that hasn't yet been published

Tags: publications, thesis, paper-submission

I'm writing a thesis for the master degree.

I'm going to include one of my conference paper in my thesis and I understand that it is common and acceptable for school regulations to include already published papers of my own work in my thesis.

But there is one problem. The defense of my thesis will be held in mid-April and this thesis will be submitted by the end of April.

But a paper I'm going to include in the thesis has been accepted by a conference and will be published sometime in June.

So, how can I cite my conference paper in the process of publication in my thesis?

Comment: Have you asked your advisor/supervisor?

Comment: @Thomas It's spring break of my school, so I asked here first.

Comment: Ask your supervisor, even though it is a spring break they will normally check email etc and reply - but probably slower than normal...

Answer (score 9):

> How can I cite a conference paper that has been accepted but not published?

Cite the paper as if it were published (albeit without page numbers, etc.) and add ***to appear*** at the end of the citation.

Comment: As someone who once had issues with a committee on this, I would suggest the more unambiguous "in press".

Comment: @MartinArgerami I've never seen such usage, but that seems perfectly reasonable. Looking for some numbers: *to appear* has ~4.01 million hits (https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22to+appear%22) whereas *in press* has ~4.19 million (https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22in+press%22)

Comment: @user2768 I don't trust that count; ["et al" only shows up 10 million times](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q="et+al").  ;)

Answer (score 3):

1) Check with your supervisor.

2) G. Lee & A. Supervisor (2019) "Awesome Conference Paper", in Very Good Conference Proceedings, accepted.

Comment: I think "to appear" is more common than "accepted"

Comment: I'll accept that. Published conference  proceedings aren't really a thing in my field.

Comment: @Thomas: I agree that is more common, but I once had to go throuh an unpleasant situation due to (active research) faculty members not knowing what it meant.

Answer (score -1):

The way I know it, you'd do:

G. Lee & A. Supervisor (t.a.) "Awesome Conference Paper", to appear in Very Good Conference Proceedings.

(Shamelessly stealing all the words from masher's answer.)